# alternate way to execute function in select statement for each record

Tags: sql

alternate way to execute function in select statement for each record.

i have select statement which has fixed column from table with calculated column,so to calculate column i am using function .this function gets call for each record.
so is there any alternate way to do it ?

example :

```
select ProductName,
ProductCode,
dbo.fn_MinPriceByGroupId_DiscountCode(PS1.Product_Id) as Price 
from tbl_Product
```

now problem is to call function for each row would impact on speed so is there any alternate way to do it.

Comment: PS1 is must be tbl_product alias right?

Comment: There are always alternate ways, these can often be even worse :) What is your logic in Price function? If you could rewrite it to set based logic (using queries, CTEs etc), then you could link these queries to your products and (maybe) get better performance.

Comment: Unless the result of the function is the same for all rows, e.g. `select ProductName, ProductCode, db_name()`, if you want to get a value for each record, you need to call the function for each record, no way around that.

Comment: @Arvo:What do u mean by set based logic

Comment: @user2787096, set based logic means that instead of taking a single value and calculating on each row, you use a JOIN condition or some other method of processing multiple rows at once.  Google the phrase and see if you can find an article or two.  In the meantime, though, why don't you post the code for your function and explain what it's trying to do?